# How to change background color of a table's td using Class Selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to change the background color of a cell (**td**) based on certain condition. I access the cell using the cell's **class** like this:

```
$(document).on("focusout", clsCellCurr, function() {    // "clsCellCurr" is class of the cell
    if ... {             // My conditional statement/s
    // Here I want to change the background color if a particular condition is not met
            $('.clsCellCurr').css('background-color', "red");    // Using 'class' selector does not work

    // Whereas this works
            $('#'+id_CellCurr).css('background-color', "red");    // Using "id" Works
    }                   // End of conditional statement/s
});
```

However the above does not change the background color even if a condition is met (or not met).

**What am I doing wrong? Can I not use the class selector for the job?**

Comment: Where is the `clsCellCurr` variable defined? What values does it have?

Comment: Try : `$('table tr td .clsCellCurr').css('background-color', "red");`

Comment: please update question with html code

Comment: what is your exact requirment

Comment: @Phil - Perhaps I am not getting something, but using the same class selector `clsCellCurr` I am accessing it. And using `id` works perfectly.

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar - No. **Not working.** Can you explain your `$('table tr td ...);`? Why does any one need to trace the path to the cell which has just been accessed? Moreover, like I have already pointed out, using **id** works.

Comment: Please post your full html and jQuery code. See what is [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: @12379095 I think you misunderstood my question. In the first line of your code, you have a **variable** `clsCellCurr`. Where does this come from and what is its value?